# Why is Process Explorer not showing the .Net information in the .Net columns?

Tags: c#, .net-framework

I see the process but the Heap Bytes, Gen 0 Collection cols are blank.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Besides not being programming related, this question is also very sparse on details. Are you looking at a common program (in which case, which one?), or something that's unique to yourself?

Comment: The common program is ProcessExplorer from SysInternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try set up symbols under Options.  I can see Gen 0 fine in version 14.

Keep in mind that it only shows up for processes with CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this behavior for tiny .net applications (like just `while(true){}` ).
Process Explorer uses Windows performance counters to display this kind of data. 
The whole .net memory counters category will be empty before the first GC (garbage collection).